# Foundation Abide matching line breaks

Tags: javascript, regex, zurb-foundation, abide

I am trying to use foundation abide to make error when my form is submitted. I cannot grasp how to allow any character to pass (limited 2000) and allow line breaks:

My code

```
trainerDescription : /^.{0,1999}$/,
```

Comment: Ok thank you I had to put a / in the front & end of the expression to get it to work but it does now. So for abide the pattern                      istrainerDescription : /^.{0,1999}$/,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since javascript won't support `(?s)` dotall modifier, you could use `[\s\S]` regex to match any space or non-space character. Note that `\s` would match any kind of whitespaces (*vertical or horizontal*).

```
/^[\s\S]{0,1999}$/m
```